# Variable scope, can't access the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, youtube-api

I can't assign the current time to my variable 'currentTime', any idea how to get a workaround to let the variable get che current time of the video? it's seem a classic problem about scope variable, but i can't get a solution, any tips? thanks !

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  currentTime = 0;

  ngOnInit() {

    let player;
    let myTimer;


    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = function () {
      player = new window['YT'].Player('video', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerReady
        }
      });
    };

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data === 1) { // playing
          myTimer = setInterval(() => {
            const time = player.getCurrentTime();
            console.log(time); // I want to set the currentTime declared on top equal to player.getCurrentTime();
          }, 100);
        } else { // not playing
          clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    }

    if (!window['YT']) {
      const tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/player_api';
      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    }
  }


  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Thanks for all your responses, it's ended by me doing the classic this trick but after reading : [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback), It's ended using the bind function.
The weird part of that code is that without the 'checkCurrentTime' interval the currentTime is not updated on html layout, definetly don't understand why.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  tempoAttuale = 0;

  ngAfterViewInit() {


    let player;
    let myTimer;

    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = function () {
      player = new window['YT'].Player('video', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    };

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    const tis = this;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      if (event.data === 1) { // playing
        myTimer = setInterval(() => {
          const time = player.getCurrentTime();
          tis.tempoAttuale = time;
        }, 100);
      } else { // not playing
        clearInterval(myTimer);
      }
    }

    /*
    I don't know why, but thanks to that the value of 'tempoAttuale' time on html is updated
     */
    const checkCurrentTime = setInterval(() => {
    }, 100);


    if (!window['YT']) {
      const tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/player_api';
      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Define the callbacks as arrow functions: (1) `window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = () => { ... }`, (2) `private onPlayerStateChange = (event) => { ...; this.currentTime = time; ... }`, (3) and set `onStateChange: this.onPlayerStateChange` (and do (2) and (3) for `onPlayerReady` also).

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks, i readed the other question and it's work! but seems not to understand why i need the strange timeout to get the data updated on screen